# How to sort hash values in Redis?

Tags: database, hash, redis, nosql

Here I have 3 Hashes and I used sadd to define the relations

```
 hmset user:1 name Jack
 hmset category:1 name music
 hmset instrument:1 name guitar 

 sadd user:1:category 1 sadd category:1:instrument 1
```

So in this case if I want to get user's instrument how should write my command? this didnt work

```
Sort User:1:Category:Instrument Get Category*:->Instrument
```

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, it is unclear from your question what it is that you're trying to do - perhaps adding more details about the data's structure and the end result that you're looking for would help. Try explaining the relationships between the user, category and instruments entities and the type of query you're looking to run.

That said, there are several problems that are apparent as is:

1. Note that key names are case sensitive so when calling `SORT` (or any command for that matter) make sure you use key names with the same case you used to create the keys. That means the `foo`, `Foo`, `FOO` and `FoO` are all different key names.
2. Your `SADD` statement will result in a single Set with the following contents:

   ```
   127.0.0.1:6379> sadd user:1:category 1 sadd category:1:instrument 1
   (integer) 3
   127.0.0.1:6379> smembers user:1:category
   1) "category:1:instrument"
   2) "1"
   3) "sadd"
   ```

To create multiple sets you'll need to issue separate `SADD` commands, once for each Set.

3. Use Sets to express 1:N relationships, e.g. a user can have multiple instruments. To express a 1:1 relationship, simply add a field to your Hash, i.e.:

   ```
   127.0.0.1:6379> hmset user:1 name Jack instrument 1
   OK
   127.0.0.1:6379> hgetall user:1
   1) "name"
   2) "Jack"
   3) "instrument"
   4) "1"
   ```

On the other hand, if your user can have N instruments, use a Set:

```
    SADD user:1:instruments 1 2 3
```

4. Assuming a user has multiple instruments, getting the instruments' names is done with `SORT` like so:

   ```
   SORT user:1:instruments BY nosort GET instrument:*->name
   ```

Comment: Thanks for answer.I wanted to make these two relations; user-category and category-instrument.(I use sadd for these).And I was looking for a command that I can get the related instruments for user:1.Ofcourse  SADD user:1:instruments 1 2 3 and SORT user:1:instruments BY nosort GET instrument:*->name works well.But I am wondering Do I really need relation between user and instruments to get the name of instruments?Why I am asking this because there are already relations between user-category and category-instrument.

Comment: The category is useful if you want to store a collection of instruments that can be shared between users. Getting the names of instruments using the user->category->instruments relationship can't be done with a single call to `SORT` - you'll have to precede it with a `HGET user category` and use that value to fetch the instruments set for the category with `SORT`.